# Using one instance of client for external service throughout rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, salesforce

This question isn't about a specific external service, but about using the same object throughout an application to prevent re-authentication at every call. I'm building a ruby on rails application that connects to the Salesforce REST API via [restforce](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce). As of right now, I create an instance of the restforce object (client) inside of every controller. This slows my application down significantly because it is authenticating into salesforce's api on every page load.

As of right now, I have an initializer file that creates a restforce object that includes the credentials (oauth token, etc.). I would like to use that instance of the client throughout the application to speed things up. At the very least, I would like to authenticate once in each controller so each method has access to one authenticated instance of the object.

**restforce.rb (initializer file)**
require 'restforce'

```
class RestforceClient
  def restforce
    client = Restforce.new :username => ENV['SALESFORCE_USERNAME'],
      :password       => ENV['SALESFORCE_PASSWORD'],
      :security_token => ENV['SALESFORCE_SECURITY_TOKEN'],
      :client_id      => ENV['SALESFORCE_CLIENT_ID'],
      :client_secret  => ENV['SALESFORCE_CLIENT_SECRET'],
      :host           => ENV['SALESFORCE_HOST'],
      :debugging      => ENV['TRUE']
  end
end
```

**controller example**

```
def foobar
  @user = current_user
  client = Restforce.new
  @fetchdata = client.query("select X from y")
end

def barfoo
  @user = current_user
  client = Restforce.new    
  @fetchdata = client.query("select X from Z")
end
```

The above controller illustrates the problem I'm encountering. When I load the foobar view, It creates a new instance of restforce. Then when I load the barfoo view, it creates a new instance of restforce. Is there anyway to have one instance of restforce across the controller, or even better, the whole application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is the better way for you:

```
#config/initializers/client.rb

class RestforceClient
  include Singleton

  def restforce
    @client ||= \
      Restforce.new :username => ENV['SALESFORCE_USERNAME'],
        :password       => ENV['SALESFORCE_PASSWORD'],
        :security_token => ENV['SALESFORCE_SECURITY_TOKEN'],
        :client_id      => ENV['SALESFORCE_CLIENT_ID'],
        :client_secret  => ENV['SALESFORCE_CLIENT_SECRET'],
        :host           => ENV['SALESFORCE_HOST'],
        :debugging      => ENV['TRUE']
  end
end

# app/controllers/application_controller.rb

private

def client
  RestforceClient.instance.restforce
end
helper_method :client
```

After that you can simply use it:

```
# controller

def foobar
  @user = current_user
  @fetchdata = client.query("select X from y")
end

# view 

<%= client.query("select X from y") %>

# other services

class MyService
  def some_methods
    result = RestforceClient.instance.restforce
    #...
  end
end
```

`RestforceClient` will create `Restforce` instance only once.

If you want `client` method in the `AR` models you can do this:

```
# config/initializers/extend_ar.rb

module ActiveRecordExtension
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def client
     RestforceClient.instance.restforce
  end
end

# include the extension 
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtension)
```

Comment: This works great. I don't completely understand why this works so I need to dig in a bit further. Can I access the helper_method from a model?

Comment: Feel free to ask me any questions. In model you can't use the helper methods. You should use `RestforceClient.instance.restforce` instead.

Comment: How would I go about rescuing exceptions with this solution. Do I just wrap the @client in a begin rescue block with the exceptions I want to rescue? I'm concerned about timeouts because this is an external service. Thanks!

Comment: I think the best way is catching exceptions in the `RestforceClient#restforce` method.

Comment: Would this present an issue with multithreading? And if yes, is there a way to resolve it?

Comment: Thank you, ole. One more question: any reason to not use @eloyesp's example below? I already implemented it on in a low-traffic environment and am not experiencing any issues.

Comment: Nope, you can use it without any restriction. But I wouldn't recommend storing the class instance in the constant, it looks a bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative to use Singleton module is to simply use a Constant that you can setup in an Initializer of some sort.

```
RestforceClient = Restforce.new :username => ENV['SALESFORCE_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SALESFORCE_PASSWORD'],
    :security_token => ENV['SALESFORCE_SECURITY_TOKEN'],
    :client_id      => ENV['SALESFORCE_CLIENT_ID'],
    :client_secret  => ENV['SALESFORCE_CLIENT_SECRET'],
    :host           => ENV['SALESFORCE_HOST'],
    :debugging      => ENV['TRUE']
```

The only advantage of a singleton class is the initial time. But this is not an issue with RestForce (and should not be an issue with most clients).